# how to rename multiple files by replacing string in file name? this string contains a "#"

Tags: sed, rename, mv

https://serverfault.com/questions/70939/how-to-replace-a-text-string-in-multiple-files-in-linux

https://serverfault.com/questions/228733/how-to-rename-multiple-files-by-replacing-word-in-file-name

https://serverfault.com/questions/212153/replace-string-in-files-with-certain-file-extension

https://serverfault.com/questions/33158/searching-a-number-of-files-for-a-string-in-linux

These mentioned articles have all answered my question. However none of them work for me. I suspect it is because the string I am trying to replace has a # in it. Is there a special way to address this?

I have image file that had an é replaced by #U00a9 during a site migration. These look like this:

```
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-80x60.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-125x125.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-150x150.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-250x250.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-282x232.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-300x150.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-300x200.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-300x250.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-360x240.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-400x250.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-430x270.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-480x240.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-600x240.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-600x250.jpg
Lucky-#U00a9NBC.jpg
```

and I want to change it to something like this:

```
Lucky-safeNBC-80x60.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-125x125.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-150x150.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-250x250.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-282x232.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-300x150.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-300x200.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-300x250.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-360x240.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-400x250.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-430x270.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-480x240.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-600x240.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC-600x250.jpg
Lucky-safeNBC.jpg
```

UPDATE:

These examples all start with "LU00a9ucky but here are many images with different names. I am simply  targeting the "#U00a9" portion of the string to replace with "safe".

Comment: So what have you actually tried?  I see that you have linked to a few questions and say they failed, but how did they fail?  IMO the best example uses the `rename` command.  I suspect your rename would be as simple as `rename -n 's/#/safeNBC/' *.jpg`.

Comment: I tried `rename -n 's/#U00a9/safe/' *.jpg` and the command was accepted but no changes occurred.

Comment: Sure, as you would have seen from the documentation you surely reviewed, the `-n` is the `no act` option.  Which lets you see if it works before you actually use it.  Did the output on the screen show the potential new names correctly?

Comment: I apologize I copied and pasted your example without paying full attention, I did the rename command without the -n. I believe @DTK address the problem, I was not escaping the #.

Comment: Replacing strings in filenames on MacOS: https://superuser.com/questions/152627/renaming-many-files-in-mac-os-x-batch-processing

Comment: For arch (rename from utils-linux 2.34, check using rename -V) you can do: `rename expression replacment file` e.g. to replace the string foo with bar for all files you do `rename 'foo' 'bar' *`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is not hard, simply make sure to escape the octothorpe (#) in the name by prepending a reverse-slash (\).

```
find . -type f -name 'Lucky-*' | while read FILE ; do
    newfile="$(echo ${FILE} |sed -e 's/\\#U00a9/safe/')" ;
    mv "${FILE}" "${newfile}" ;
done
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, escaping the `#` sounds like what I need. I do not see a backslash in your example. Should it look like this:        `s/\#U00a9/safe/`

Answer (score 171):

To replace `#` by `somethingelse` for filenames in the current directory (not recursive) you can use the (Perl-)[rename](https://man.archlinux.org/man/rename.1p.en) utility:

```
rename  's/#/somethingelse/' *
```

Characters like `-` must be escaped with a `\`.

For your case, you would want to use

```
rename 's/#U00a9/safe/g' *
```

Note that if you only want to operate on a certain selection of files, e.g., only `*.jpg`, adjust the final input to match that selection:

```
rename 's/#U00a9/safe/g' *.jpg
```

To perform a test before actually changing filenames, use the `-n` flag:

```
demo/> ls                               
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-125x125.jpg  
Lucky-#U00a9NBC-150x150.jpg 

demo/> rename -n 's/#U00a9/safe/g' *.jpg
rename(Lucky-#U00a9NBC-125x125.jpg, Lucky-safeNBC-125x125.jpg)
rename(Lucky-#U00a9NBC-150x150.jpg, Lucky-safeNBC-150x150.jpg)
```

For OS X, rename can be installed using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/): `brew install rename`.

Comment: This did not work on my machine (Arch Linux), but mik's answer did.

Comment: @marcvangend Which version of `rename` are you using?  `# sudo pacman -S perl-rename` will install the perl version, which is more powerful and might be enough to make this answer work for you.

Comment: @JohnGowers Thanks! I didn't realize there are two versions. On my system, `rename --version` returns `rename from util-linux 2.29.2` so that is indeed not the perl version.

Comment: There are two common `rename` utilities but neither of them are developed by GNU: Debian-based distributions include a `rename` utility with their Perl package while Red Hat-based distributions use the `rename` utility from the `util-linux` from the Linux Kernel Organization. Your link is to the `rename` C **function** from the GNU standard library.

Comment: In this answer, why do we have to write `/g` in `rename 's/#U00a9/safe/g' *`

Comment: No need for all of that, just use option `--subst` or `--subst-all` of `rename` as stated in my answer

Comment: waiting for the reason for `/g` as @Nikhil pointed

Comment: In my version of `rename` (`rename from util-linux 2.23.2` from CentOS), the syntax is: `rename old new files`. E.g.: `rename "#" "somethingelse" *`

Comment: /g means global search, i.e. once it finds and replaces an instance of the string, it will keep searching the filename for more instances. So foo_foo.jpg would become bar_bar.jpg. If you didn't put the g, foo_foo.jpg would become bar_foo.jpg instead (only the first instance of 'foo' would change)

Answer (score 54):

find the list of files and then replace keyword.
below is example

```
find . -name '*jpg' -exec bash -c ' mv $0 ${0/\#U00a9NBC/safeNBC}' {} \;
```

Comment: You need some double-quotes around your `mv` arguments, in case there are spaces in the name

Comment: I needed to replace all files *_spec.rb to *_controller_spec.rb and your solution worked for me. Thanx.

Comment: For anyone wondering, yes this is recursive.

Comment: It worked. however it is matching all other files and trying to rename/mv files. I.e mv: `'./jhon-654x1024-100x70.jpg' and './jhon-654x1024-100x70.jpg' are the same file`. Probably need little more tweaking to skip trying for files which are outside of match

Comment: getting: `new target ....... is not a directory` for each file it tries to process.

Comment: Elegant and powerful.

Answer (score 40):

To escape `#` from the shell, just use single quotes (`'#'`), double quotes (`"#"`), or backslash (`\#`).

The simplest in your case would be to use the `rename` command (if it is available):

```
rename '#U00a9' safe *.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks. While the highest voted answer (`rename  's/#/somethingelse/' *`) didn't work on my machine (Arch Linux), this one did.

Comment: This works using the rename command from util-linux.

Comment: Any reason why neither of these work in Arch Linux in Dec 2022?

Comment: @lockheed, what is the error? do you have the rename executable at all?

Comment: No error. The command runs without any effect or output.

Comment: @lockheed, maybe your rename is not from util-linux package, the other syntax `rename  's/#U00a9/safe/' *.jpg` may work in this case

Answer (score 26):

not sure how to in sed, but you can try this in a bash shell:

```
for f in Lucky-#U00a9NBC-*.jpg; do mv -v "$f" "${f/#U00a9/safe}"; done;
```

explanation:

1. loops through all file names matching the glob (Lucky-#U00a9NBC-*.jpg)
2. renames file using the move command(mv)
3. uses native bash parameter substitution ${var/Pattern/Replacement} to craft the new name ("${f/#U00a9/safe}")

More on parameter substitution (which is highly underutilized IMO): http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: this one works for me, on windows using git bash terminal. none of the above worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The above examples were not working on my system (CentOS 5.6) so I found a (possibly more  system-specific) command that works (note: need to escape '#' with `\` on command line):

`rename \#U00a9 safe *.jpg`

[Also: I don't have enough reputation yet to comment, so in response to Nikhil's question regarding the use of `/g` in `rename 's/old_string/new_string/g'` (posed in the comments for another answer above):

Use the `g` modifier to perform a 'global' substitution (that is, to substitute new_string for old_string as many times as old_string occurs). This shouldn't be necessary in my answer because the `rename` will be applied to all files specified with `*`. See https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm for a concise explanation of this and other modifiers.]

Comment: Correct; Fedora-derived OSes like CentOS have a different version of `rename` than Debian-derived OSes.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238862/135943.  And by the way, CentOS 5.6 is quite old and I recommend you upgrade.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation + link. The outdated OS is at work and so it isn't up to me to upgrade :) but a new cluster is being built out and presumably we'll upgrade when we move over...

Answer (score 1):

Actually `rename` has an option exactly for that called `--subst` or `-s` in short. No need to use the regex syntax.

```
rename -s '#U00a9' 'safe' *
```

If you want to replace/substitute multi occurrences, use `--subst-all` or `-S`.

BTW, I only wanted to replace a string by nothing (remove it from file name)... well we also have an option for it `-d/--delete` and `-D/--delete-all`:

```
rename -d '#U00a9' *
```

Comment: I'd really like the last part as well. But `rename` does not have the `-d` option as far as I can see... 
[Link](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html)

Comment: @Klinghust I guess I was talking about the version of `rename` you get when doing `brew install rename` on a Mac, which is this one: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rename

Answer (score 0):

Here's DTK's solution wrapped in reusable bash function:

```bash
function renameFilesRecursively () {

  SEARCH_PATH="$1"
  SEARCH="$2"
  REPLACE="$3"

  find ${SEARCH_PATH} -type f -name "*${SEARCH}*" | while read FILENAME ; do
      NEW_FILENAME="$(echo ${FILENAME} | sed -e "s/${SEARCH}/${REPLACE}/g")";
      mv "${FILENAME}" "${NEW_FILENAME}";
  done

}
```

Here's how you can use it:

```
renameFilesRecursively /home/user/my-files apple orange
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

```
ls Lucky-#U00a9NBC*.jpg
```

Will display all `jpg` file names with `Lucky-#U00a9NBC*`

```
rename 's/Lucky-#U00a9NBC/Lucky-safeNBC/' *.jpg
```

After executing this command every `Lucky-#U00a9NBC` replace with `Lucky-safeNBC`.

```
 ls Lucky-safeNBC*.jpg
```

You can see all files are renamed

Comment: Why are you demonstrating that the pattern `Lucky-#U00a9NBC*.jpg` matches the names and then you don't use this fact when actually renaming the files? As far as we know, there may be other files matching the `*.jpg` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say more likely `#U00a9` is intended to be standing for the character U+00A9 here (`©`).

If you wanted to turn it back to `©`, encoded in the locale's charset, you could do with the `perl` variants of `rename` (sometimes called `prename`):

```
rename '
  use Encode::Locale;
  use Encode;
  s/#U([0-9a-f]{4})/chr hex $1/gie;
  $_ = encode(locale_fs => $_)' ./*'#'[uU]*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows using cygwin, then what works is:

```shell
find . -type f -exec rename PhraseToReplace PlaceToReplaceWith {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use `pyRenamer`, an application made specifically for batch renaming.

It can be installed with `sudo apt-get install pyrenamer`

For usage details, refer to [its README file on GitHub](https://github.com/SteveRyherd/pyRenamer/blob/master/README).

Comment: If you really think this could answer the question please add some explanation to your answer. Of itself, it only installs a package. You should explain what the command does and provide an example that handles the OP's specific requirement.