# Find all [filename].mp4 and rename [filename].audio

Tags: files, find, rename

So I have a script that adds 2 films together using the audio from the `$1.audio` file. What I would like to do is rename any file in the directory with:

```
*.mp4
```

To:

```
*.audio
```

Keeping original file name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `rename` command.  It's not portable, but it exists in different forms in different distributions.

**In CentOS/RHEL and probably Fedora:**

```
rename .mp4 .audio *.mp4
```

Should do it.  From `man rename` on CentOS 6:

```
SYNOPSIS
       rename from to file...
       rename -V

DESCRIPTION
       rename  will  rename  the specified files by replacing the first occur-
       rence of from in their name by to.
```

**In Ubuntu and probably any Debian variant:**

```
rename 's/\.mp4$/.audio/' *.mp4
```

should do it.  From `man rename` on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
SYNOPSIS
       rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]

DESCRIPTION
       "rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified
       as the first argument.  The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression
       which is expected to modify the $_ string in Perl for at least some of
       the filenames specified.  If a given filename is not modified by the
       expression, it will not be renamed.  If no filenames are given on the
       command line, filenames will be read via standard input.

       For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the
       extension, you might say

               rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
```

Comment: This is the shortest working code which I prefer, love the dual OS answer's... seperate thread really, but what does "portable" mean

Comment: "Portable" means a command/tool would work the same on various distributions or various OSes.  Portability isn't actually a simple yes/no; something can be more portable or less portable because of the wide variety of Linux distributions available, not to mention other OSes.  `rename` differs widely from distribution to distribution even for simple use cases, so I said it's "not portable".  `find`, on the other hand (see jilliagre's answer), is *very* portable as it will work in any Linux distribution you're likely to *ever* encounter.

Comment: Indeed, and not only any Linux distributions but on any Unix and Unix like distribution too.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fast and portable solution still handling oddly named files :

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec sh -c 'for i do mv -- "$i" "${i%.mp4}.audio"; done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Portable means that will work on any Unix/Unix like distribution. The answer you accepted rely on a command that is not standardized, that has a different syntax depending on the implementations, and that might be or is missing on many Unix distributions (freeBSD, OpenBSD, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX) and probably in some Linux ones.

Comment: Your answer is definitely the best portable solution.  +1.  :)  If it's for a personal script (like I suspect from the question), it will only need to be run on one distribution, and `rename` is definitely more *readable*.

Answer (score 2):

Use this `for` loop:

```
for f in *; do
  [ -f "$f" ] && mv -v -- "$f" "${f%.mp3}.audio"
done
```

- `for i in *` loops trough all files and directories (except dot-files) in the current working directory and stores the current processed file in `$f`

  - `[ -f "$f" ]` checks if it's a regular file
  - `mv -v` renames the file (`--` is that the filenames will not be interpreted as arguments by mistake)
  - `${f%.mp3}.audio` removes the `.mp3` extension and adds the `.audio` extension ([Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02))

Comment: That's actually very clean as well as portable.  It's readable enough, for those who know shell scripting fairly well.  I think I would use this myself even in preference to my accepted answer of using `rename`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses `find`, `sed`, and `xargs`. This solution works even if there are spaces in the name.

It first gets the files using `find`. Then, gets the base name of the file using `sed`. Finally, it does the move to change the extension.

Note the code below is multi-line for clarity.
You should probably execute it in one line.

```
# split into three lines for clarity
# should execute as one line
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.mp4'
| sed -r 's/.*\/([^/]+)\.mp4/\1/g'
| xargs -ix mv "x.mp4" "x.audio"
```

Below is an alternative solution using `basename`. This solution *may* work with names containing spaces (have not tested this one).

It first gets all the files with `.mp4` extension, then gets the base name, and finally renames each with the audio extension.

```
# split into three lines for clarity
# should execute as one line
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.mp4' -print0
| xargs -0 -ix basename "x" .mp4
| xargs -ix mv "x.mp4" "x.audio"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
for file in `ls *.mp4`; { mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/.mp4/.audio/g'`; }
```

Comment: This will fail given *any* special characters in filenames—even a space will cause it to fail, to say nothing of newlines or other trickery.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs on why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: What kind of undocumented `for`-loop construct is that?  It doesn't work in `dash`, but works in `bash` and `zsh`.  I vaguely remember seeing this syntax before, but it's been literally decades ago.  Is it a `ksh` thing?  It's really kind of neat, substitute `{` for `do`, and `}` for `done`.

Comment: I think its short form of for..do..done. It works in bash, and I didn't test it on any other shells.

Comment: @Soheil - Yes that's what I said.  Where did you learn it?

Comment: @RobertL From my colleagues.