# Bulk rename, change suffix?

Tags: files, filenames, rename

How can I bulk replace the suffix for many files?

I have a lot of files like

- `NameSomthing-min.png`
- `NameSomthing1-min.png`
- `NameSomthing2-min.png`

I would like to change all them to

- `NameSomthing.png`
- `NameSomthing1.png`
- `NameSomthing2.png`

i.e., remove the characters `-min` from the name. 
How would I do this?

Comment: Check `man rename`; it probably exists on your system.  [Here is an example usage of `rename`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238862/135943).

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your shell. I use `zsh`, and this is the way I do it:

```
for i in *-min.*; do mv $i "${i%-*}.${i#*.}"; done
```

I advice checking out the manpage of your shell, and checking out a section similar to "parameter expansion" (as it is called in the [`zsh` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn)).

Similar solutions are available for `bash` and other shells as well (you did not specify which one you use).

Please note, that your particular solution always depends on the data and your goal. if you have the '-' as separator between the name and the suffix you want to get rid of, this is the way to go. If not, you might want to tailor the param expansion a little bit.

Comment: Be sure to `echo` first time otherwise u end up with a mess of u screw up.

Comment: Isn't this more bash-like solution? `zsh` has `zmv` to avoid the loop.

Comment: @orion my zsh doesn't recognize `zmv`. Also, the more universal, the better, I'd say. Especially in this particular case.

Comment: You must load these extensions. `autoload -U zmv` in your `.zshrc`. True, portability is ok in scripts, but not when you need to do something quickly and easily in the command line.  `zsh` is known precisely for little magic things that do complicated things automatically via builtin behaviour. It's for power users that don't mind investing time into learning and configuring their tool. The rest of us just stick with `bash`.

Comment: @orion: it took me roughly 20 sec to come up with that one-liner. I found it much more difficult writing this answer, with all the markup and such. So sure, I'll put it in my `.zshrc`, but I'll keep using my one-liners.

Comment: I know, I use these too (I'm on bash). I'm just saying, I bet that after you get used to these commands, they are handy shortcuts.

Comment: @orion I'd argue the pattern replacements are one of the most powerful tools across shells. Things like `for i in *; do mv $i ${i:l}; done` to quickly get rid of uppercase file names (the likes which usually come from WIndows or DOS), etc.

Comment: This almost works in bash — it does `mv NameSomthing-min.png NameSomthingpng`.  Don't you need to put a `.` between the `${i%-*}` and the `${i#*.}`?

Comment: @Scott you're completely right. What a dumb oversight on my part ¦s

Answer (score 1):

This script may help:

```
for file in *-min.png; do
    echo mv "$file" "${file%-min.png}.png"
done
```

Remove the echo to actually execute the command.

Comment: This works, but I'm giving the benefit of the doubt, since he didn't quite specify if these are just `.png` files. So it seems the delimiter before the extension is the only thing we can count on?

Comment: @polemon  I am playing it safe, being strict on what may get changed will make less of a problem for the user if the user is not careful (or has some basic knowledge of how CLI works).