# Build a Renaming Script

Tags: shell-script

write a script that will check each folder/directory and rename the folder title if it contains the word “section.” The folder should be renamed to use the word “chapter” instead of “section”;Your script should be recursive, executing on each directory, subdirectory, and lower subdirectory, until all child directories have been checked and renamed.

**For example:**

`supersectiondir-->subsectiondir-->lowersubsectiondir`
should become:
`superchapterdir-->subchapterdir-->lowersubchapterdir`

**My attempt (from directory above supersectiondir):**

```
find /c/Users/cmd2/supersection -type d -exec sed -i 's/section/chapter/g' {} \; 

$ sh renaming.sh

sed: couldn't edit /c/Users/cmd2/supersection: not a regular file
sed: couldn't edit /c/Users/cmd2/supersection/subsection: not a regular file
sed: couldn't edit /c/Users/cmd2/supersection/subsection/lowersubsection: not a regular file
```

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like homework... What is your specific question?

Comment: i want to rename the directories and sub-directories.
for ex: supersectiondir-->subsectiondir-->lowersubsectiondir it should become: superchapterdir-->subchapterdir-->lowersubchapterdir

Comment: (shopt -s nullglob && _() { for P in "$1"*/; do Q="${P//section/chapter}"; mv  -- "$P" "$Q"; _ "$Q"; done } && _ ./)  

Try this this will solve the problem

Comment: thank you for the help :)  this worked 
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
for file in `find -name '*section*'`
do
mv $file ${file//section/chapter}
done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rename` tool is extremely non-portable; there is almost nothing in common between the RHEL/CentOS/Fedora family version of `rename` and the version found on Ubuntu or Debian.

I wrote an [answer giving example usage for both versions of `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238862/135943) a while back.

You haven't said what OS you're using, so it's hard to be very specific—and **since this is homework, you should do some work on it yourself** so I will not spell out the answer even if you say which OS.

However, a couple of tips:

- `sed` operates on the *contents* of a *text file*; it does not change the name of a file and certainly not the name of a directory.  It cannot be used for that, and that's why you get errors from the command you wrote.
- You are on the correct track with your `find` command.
- I suggest you look up the `-name` and `-iname` operators for `find` as they may come in handy (you don't need to try to rename files that don't match the given pattern).
- Using `-exec` with `rename` (the appropriate version for your OS) is probably the easiest/best solution for this.

Comment: The OS should not matter for a shell script. Aim to be portable across all *nixs.

Comment: thank you for the help :)  this worked 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for file in `find -name '*section*'`
do
mv $file ${file//section/chapter}
done

Comment: @jayineedesai, see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)  And also [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)  What you want is: `find -name '*section*' -exec sh -c 'for f do mv "$f" "${f//section/chapter}"; done' find-sh {} +`, although if `section` appears in a directory name this will still behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `rename` tool. An example of this use case is:

```
rename section chapter *
```

Or in your case, you would probably pipe the output of find.

```
find . -type d -print | xargs rename section chapter
```

Comment: $ sh renaming.sh
xargs: rename: No such file or directory
this is what it comes up with.please help

Comment: thank you for the help :)  this worked 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for file in `find -name '*section*'`
do
mv $file ${file//section/chapter}
done