# renaming files in a folder

Tags: centos, rename

In one directory I have many files which look like this:

`Galaxy100-[0025-CL3.single.bed].bed`

and I would like to change it to:

`0025-CL3.single.bed`

I tried this `rename 's/Galaxy[0-9] - \[//' *`, but it did not change anything.

How is possible to rename these files?

Comment: Look at `man rename`; you are using the wrong syntax for the version of `rename` on your OS.  Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238862/135943

Comment: You're only matching a single digit after `Galaxy`. You need to use `[0-9]+` to match any number of digits. And you shouldn't have spaces around `-`.

Comment: You need `prename`, not `rename` (`rename` is only `prename` on Debian and derivatives).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't match the pattern in your filename. To match at least one digit, you need to use `[0-9]+` (you can also use `\d` to match digits); your pattern will only match 1 digit. Your example filename doesn't have spaces around `-`, but you have them in the pattern. And you're not doing anything to remove the `]` at the end. Try:

```
rename 's/Galaxy\d+-\[(.*)\].*/$1/' Galaxy*
```

Comment: In CentOS 6 it did not work, but it work almost in Ubuntu 14.04 and I got `0025-CL3.single.bed.bed`. How is it possible to remove the file extension?

Comment: I've changed the pattern to match everything after the `]`.