# How to batch rename files by exchanging substrings in the filenames?

Tags: bash, shell, rename

I have files like `ABC_asd_f.txt`, `DEF_qwe_r.txt`, ...

How can I exchange the uppercases before the first underscore with the lowercases after? So `ABC_asd_f.txt` becomes `asd_f_ABC.txt`, `DEF_qwe_r.txt` becomes `qwe_r_DEF.txt`, ...

Comment: I gave a [couple examples of using `rename`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238862/135943); also see `man rename`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use perl rename. Firstly use the `-n` flag for a dry-run.

```
rename -n 's/^(...)_(..._.)/$2_$1/' *
```

Then, if you are happy, run it for real.

```
rename 's/^(...)_(..._.)/$2_$1/' *
```

### Explanation

This uses capturing groups.

- `rename 's/foo/bar/' *`: replace `foo` with `bar` for all files `*`.
- `^(...)_(..._.)`: from the beginning of the line `^`, capture the first three characters `(...)`, skip over `_`, then capture the next five characters, where the fourth is underscore `(..._.)`.
- `$2_$1`: replace the string above with the capturing groups reversed (i.e. the second, an underscore, then the first).

### Rename version

There are two `rename`s in Linux-land. You can tell if it's perl rename with the following

```
$ rename --version
perl-rename 1.9
```

The other one will give a different result.

```
$ rename --version
rename from util-linux 2.28
```

Comment: The `s` in `s///` is necessary?

Comment: @Lee The `s` indicates that the perl expression should use replacement. More information [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/_PATTERN_/_REPLACEMENT_/msixpodualngcer). You can actually use other perl expressions here, e.g. try `prename -n 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *`.

Comment: +1. For perl capture groups, `\1`, `\2` will work in most cases but `$1`, `$2` is more correct.  or even `${1}`, `${2}`.  see `man perlre` and search for `Warning on \1`.

Comment: BTW, a little-known fact about perl `rename`: you can use **ANY** perl statement(s) with it (not just `s///` or `y//` etc) even very complex perl scripts - if they change `$_`, the current file being processed will be renamed to `$_`.  Otherwise it won't be renamed.

Comment: Thanks for that @cas. I think I've hit warnings about that before, and have never really chased it up. That was a good reference. Cheers. (I've edited the answer accordingly.)

Comment: yeah, i have that sed habit too.