# Rename a bunch of files, changing several substrings

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've got a bunch of files with names like image(1) image(2) image(3)  .  I'd like to rename those en masse along the lines of image1.jpg image2.jpg etc. 
I can do it in two steps by means of curly braces , which apparently is some sort of built-in shell provision for string replacement along the lines of

```
orig="a_string"
mod=${orig/string/new_thing}
```

which takes a_string to a_new_thing. So using that in a for loop I can take care of turning the ) into .jpg

```
for f in *; do mv $f "${f/)/.jpg}" ;done
```

and then

```
for f in *; do mv $f "${f/\(/}" ;done
```

removes the (. The open paren has to be escaped , I suppose as otherwise the shell thinks its the start of something else. The close paren doesn't have to be escaped like that.
 So my question is , is there a one-liner or other better way to do this,  like using pipes.  If the parens in the filename are mucking things up then assume for the time being these parens are removed , leaving the bare problem of replacing two substrings with two other strings .

Comment: find -exec maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename multiples files using the command `rename`. In this case a working solution could be:

```
rename 's/\(//; s/\)/.jpeg/;' image*
```

Comment: You should note that this uses the Debian version of `rename`.  The syntax for the Fedora family's `rename` is *quite* different.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238862/135943

Comment: @jeremy_rutman, if this answer solved your question you should accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Wildcard Honestly I didn't know that the syntax for the Fedora family's `rename` is different. I saw the question of the link and your answer is very accurate, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change more than one thing at a time by using a double slash.

```
for f in * ; do mv "$f" "${f//[()]/}.jpg" ; done
```

Comment: this works for my specific case but isnt replacing several strings, rather removing both and tacking on something else to the end.

Comment: Then give a better example! What do you actually want to do?

Comment: i want to replace two substrings with two other strings

Answer (score 0):

I’ll address your general question of how to do multiple substitutions (specifically, in a rename,
although this may be applicable to other contexts). 
I’ll suppose that you have a bunch of files
whose names include the words “over” and “dog”,
and you want to replace them with “under” and “cat”, respectively.

#### Brute force:

```
for f in *
do
    g=${f/over/under}
    h=${g/dog/cat}
    mv -- "$f" "$h"
done
```

(The `--` protects you against undesired behavior
that could result from a filename that begins with **`-`**. 
Change the last line to `mv -- "$f" "$h".jpg` if you want.) 
Note that, if a filename contains *only* “over” ***or*** “dog”
(but not both), this will do just the one available substitution. 
If it contains “dog” and “over” (in that order),
it will still do the substitutions. 
In the case you presented, where your strings are “(“ and “)”,
you might not like these behaviors.

**P.S.** Realistically,
you should probably protect the `mv` command like this:

```
if [ "$f" != "$h" ]
then
    if [ -e "$h" ]
    then
        (Error handling)
    else
        mv -- "$f" "$h"
    fi
done
```

to avoid getting an error message when you try to rename a file to itself
(because its name didn’t contain *either* of the strings),
and to avoid clobbering an existing file
(e.g., if you have an `image(1)` file
and you also already have an `image1.jpg` file).

#### with `sed`

```
for f in *
do
    g=$(sed 's/\(.*\)over\(.*\)dog\(.*\)/\1under\2cat\3/' <<< "$f")
    mv -- "$f" "$g"
done
```

This is the opposite of the first one:
it does the substitutions only if “over” *and* “dog” *both* appear
(in that order) and not otherwise.

The `<<<` (“here string”) syntax doesn’t work in all shells. 
To do the above in a shell that doesn’t support here strings, do:

```
for f in *
do
    g=$(printf "%s" "$f" | sed 's/\(.*\)over\(.*\)dog\(.*\)/\1under\2cat\3/')
    mv -- "$f" "$g"
done
```