# how to replace a character in a set of file names?

Tags: bash, files, fedora, rename

I have a set of image like that :

```
01-12_13:20:12_1366x768.png  01-12_13:20:46_1366x768.png  01-12_13:21:01_1366x768.png  01-12_13:21:06_1366x768.png
01-12_13:20:40_1366x768.png  01-12_13:20:47_1366x768.png  01-12_13:21:02_1366x768.png  01-12_13:21:07_1366x768.png
01-12_13:20:42_1366x768.png  01-12_13:20:49_1366x768.png  01-12_13:21:03_1366x768.png  01-12_13:21:08_1366x768.png
01-12_13:20:44_1366x768.png  01-12_13:20:59_1366x768.png  01-12_13:21:04_1366x768.png  01-12_13:21:10_1366x768.png
01-12_13:20:45_1366x768.png  01-12_13:21:00_1366x768.png  01-12_13:21:05_1366x768.png
```

I need to replace every `:` to `_`. How can I do that using bash commands ?

*`(note : i love when everything is compact and one-lined)`*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop, glob and parameter expansion to achieve this:

```
for f in *:*.png; do mv -- "$f" "${f//:/_}"; done
```

Answer (score 6):

The for loop is one possible solution but i prefer `rename`.

```
rename "s/:/_/g" *
```

This tool renames multiple files according to the regex rule which is given.

Comment: i tried but didn't work for me

Comment: Whats the problem. Is there an error message?

Comment: no error message, and the file are still containing the `:`. tried in `su` and changing the quote to single but still can't run that command

Comment: Strange. I tested it here before i post. And this is one of my all time favorite commands. What OS you are using?

Comment: I had to write `rename : _ *.png`, and my `man rename` doesn't seem to accept the syntax you provided, what distro are you using ?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: i use fedora 24 maybe the rename installed package is different, thanks anyways, led me on the right path

Comment: `rename` is not portable, it exists in different forms in different distributions. Maybe this [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238856/find-all-filename-mp4-and-rename-filename-audio/238862#238862) is useful.

Comment: sometimes under the name of `prename`.

Comment: There are several tools with the name `rename`. The one we are discussing here is written by Larry Wall, in the language perl.

Comment: @ballangddang you don't need root's capabilities to rename a file. So don't do it.

Comment: @richard don't do what ?

Comment: @ballangddang use root's capabilities when renaming files. If the file is in a directory that you have write permission on, then you can rename it. If you switch to root every time that you don't know what you are doing, then it will not be long before you break your system.

Comment: How to achieve the same with mmv ?