# How to rename multiple files in a directory at the same time

Tags: shell, files, rename

I have directory say `/var/tmp/abc` which has 4 files:

```
12345-ram-3e3r5-io9490-89adu9.csv
45434-dam-qwe35-to9490-43adu9.csv
11234-cam-yy3r5-ro9490-85adu9.csv
14423-sam-hh3r5-uo9490-869du9.csv
```

I want to rename all the CSV files (find all the files & rename them) in shortest possible (probably one-liner) way to this:

```
XXXXX-ram-3e3r5-io9490-89adu9.csv
XXXXX-dam-qwe35-to9490-43adu9.csv
XXXXX-cam-yy3r5-ro9490-85adu9.csv
XXXXX-sam-hh3r5-uo9490-869du9.csv
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`rename -n 's/(\w+)/XXXXX/' *.csv`

remove the `-n` when happy.

Comment: For a suitable version of `rename`. I assume this is Larry Wall's `rename`, from the  `rename` package in Debian and derivative (and IIRC `prename` on systems of the RedHat persuasion). A very useful tool.

Comment: `perl-rename` in arch linux

Comment: @SHawarden, I've tried to execute the command and read the relevant portion of man page to understand the replace pattern, but when adding the `verbose` flag, it outputs nothing and doesn't perform the file name changes, even though the current path has files with names similar to `12345_foo.csv`. Do I have to perform any additional task to get it working (currently on Fedora 30)? It is a cleaner approach than looping. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @danieldeveloper001  Did you use `rename` or `prename`? See my comment above. `man {the command}` lists the authors at the end.

Comment: @xenoid, didn't see your comment, sorry! I've used the packaged `rename` application, right now I'm on an Ubuntu machine, but I'll check the author and git a try to `prename` when I get access to a Fedora machine! I've made a quick research now based on your comment and apparently the packaged `rename` on RedHat based systems does not support match patterns, while the `prename` does. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu then this is `rename` (which is a link to /usr/bin/file-rename, itself installed with the `rename` package).

Comment: @xenoid, tested on my fedora machine, it was really a different package, you were correct! Thanks! :)

Comment: **This only works on Debian-derived systems.**  Fedora-derived systems have a completely different `rename` command; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238862/135943

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
for f in *.csv; do mv -i -- "$f" "XXXXX-${f#*-}"; done
```

How it works:

- `for f in *.csv; do`

  This starts a loop over all `*.csv` files.
- `mv -i -- "$f" "XXXXX-${f#*-}"`

  This renames the files as you want, asking interactively before overwriting any file.
- `done`

  This marks the end of the loop.

Example:

```
$ ls -1
11234-cam-yy3r5-ro9490-85adu9.csv
12345-ram-3e3r5-io9490-89adu9.csv
14423-sam-hh3r5-uo9490-869du9.csv
45434-dam-qwe35-to9490-43adu9.csv
$ for f in *.csv; do mv -i -- "$f" "XXXXX-${f#*-}"; done
$ ls -1
XXXXX-cam-yy3r5-ro9490-85adu9.csv
XXXXX-dam-qwe35-to9490-43adu9.csv
XXXXX-ram-3e3r5-io9490-89adu9.csv
XXXXX-sam-hh3r5-uo9490-869du9.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that all your files starts with 5 numeric characters, so using the [cut command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) to replace the initial numeric files by "XXXXX".

Below, the files before the command.

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 daniel daniel 0 May 13 23:18 11111_bar_file.csv
-rw-rw-r--. 1 daniel daniel 0 May 13 22:54 12345_baz_file.csv
-rw-rw-r--. 1 daniel daniel 0 May 13 22:54 67890_foo_file.xml
```

Below, the one liner command.

```
for src in *.csv; do dst=XXXXX$(echo $src| cut -c6-); mv $src $dst; done;
```

Below, the files after the command.

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 daniel daniel 0 May 13 22:54 67890_foo_file.xml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 daniel daniel 0 May 13 22:54 XXXXX_bar_file.csv
-rw-rw-r--. 1 daniel daniel 0 May 13 23:18 XXXXX_baz_file.csv
```

**References:**

[Looping through command output in bash](https://superuser.com/questions/31464/looping-through-ls-results-in-bash-shell-script)

[Substrings in bash](https://stackabuse.com/substrings-in-bash/)

Comment: Bash can do this sort of string manipulation, no need to fork a new process for each, please the other [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518801/9452) on how.

Comment: @chx, already saw the other answers and acquired a little bit of knowledge from it, but thanks for pointing them out. Would you please elaborate on ```no need to fork a new process for each```?

Comment: `cut` is a separate binary (`/usr/bin/cut`) and running it consumes more resources than using shell built ins.

Comment: I see, it actually matters if the intent is renaming a lot of files. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

no forks:

```
ls | perl -lne '$suf=substr($_,6); rename $_, "XXXXX-$suf"'
```

When you use a shell loop, the `mv` forks once per file.  Perl's `rename` command does not.

(Perl's rename command has some restrictions, but in this specific case those restrictions don't apply.)

As for the `rename` command shown earlier, yes that works, but then you have all that confusion between two different kinds of rename and so on.  If you have the right one, great, but if not, this works too.

If you don't have the perl-rename command and can't install it, you can just do this:

```
ls | perl -lne '$old=$_; s/(\w+)/XXXXX/; rename $old, $_'
```

As you can see, this uses the same substitution shown in the top answer.  Of course the perl-rename has other bells and whistles (the top answer mentioned, `-n` already, then there's `-0`, `-f`, and so on), and the more of them you need, the more you should install that instead of rolling your own in this manner.

Comment: The usual implementations of a pipe will have forks.

Comment: I meant, "won't fork once per file to be renamed", unlike even shell, where the "mv" forks /usr/bin/mv or whatever.  This is because the "rename" command is a perl internal command that directly calls rename() in libc.  Of course it has some restrictions, but in this specific example those restrictions don't apply.

Comment: That's also true of the `rename` command ([top answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518804/70524), also uses Perl), so maybe you should add a little more explanation than simply "no forks" to the answer.