# Removing the first 4 symbols of a file name

Tags: bash, rename

I got the following problem: I want to rename files in the format of `12xy[..].log` to `[...].log`.

My problem is, that some of them have an `a` following the first time and some of them got a `v` - so I cannot use commands, that follow the logic of replacing part of the name up to a certain character. (Like an underscore etc.)

Is there anyway to rename them quickly?

Edit: There is always the same prefix of `MD18`. So for example there are some files named `MD18v230_SHAPE.log` or another one named `MD18a004_FACES.log` and so forth. I would like to have them named `v230_SHAPE.log` and `a004_FACES.log`.

Comment: Do you care about potential collisions while renaming?

Comment: Do you **always** want to remove 4 characters, or sometimes 5 characters (including the a or v)? Assuming 'Yes', you can try with a dry run: `rename -n 's/^....//' *.log` and if it looks OK, remove the option `-n` and rename the files. My `rename` is linked to Larry Wall's perl script `file-rename`. But ... beware of potential collisions while renaming!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to rename multiple files by replacing string in file name? this string contains a "#"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175135/how-to-rename-multiple-files-by-replacing-string-in-file-name-this-string-conta)

Comment: @sudodus I alwas want to delete the first 4 character of the file name :) .

Answer (score 3):

I'd use tools designed for batch renaming as they're good at making sanity checks before doing anything or have dry-run modes that show you what they would do instead of doing them.

There are several of them, the most popular ones being perl's `rename`, a very short example script that used to be shipped with `perl` since the 80s but has still evolved into something more advanced (and several variants thereof). That one can use all the power of `perl`'s string processing capabilities, so the possibilities are endless.

There's also an unrelated but very limited command called `rename` in the `util-linux` package.

`mmv` is a dedicated batch renaming tool, also from the 80s. It used to be quite popular but seems to have fallen out of fashion lately.

`zsh` comes with a `zmv` auto-loadable function that can use the full power of zsh filename generation and expansion operators.

Here, your task is relatively trivial as it's just a matter of removing the first 4 characters of files that start with `MD18`, so:

```
rename 's/^MD18//' MD18*.log
```

```
mmv 'MD18*.log' '#1.log'
```

```
autoload zmv
zmv 'MD18(*.log)' '$1'
```

You can also always use a loop in simpler shells like `bash`:

```
for file in MD18*.log; do
  mv -i "$file" "${file#MD18}"
done
```

But it won't have any of the safeguards of the specialised tools. Here we're still using `-i` though to give a chance to the user to abort before a file is lost/overridden in the process. A dry run can also be performed by prepending the command with `echo`.

Comment: you coud improve the for loop with cp instead mv, cp can create hard links and auto rename with suffix in case of collision

Answer (score 1):

Do all these filenames start with 12xy or do you want to remove the first 4 characters of the filename, whatever they be?
Are all your filenames like these - 12xy_lmn.log, 12xydef.log, 12xyabc.log, 12xyvw.log, ...?

If so, you could rename using a for loop:

```
for fn in ./12xy*.log 
do
    mv -i "$fn" "$(sed -e 's/^12xy//' <<< "$fn")"
done
```

You may change "mv -i" to "mv", if you are okay with collisions.

If, however, you want to remove the first 4 characters in the filename, whatever they are, use:

```
for fn in ./*.log 
do
    mv -i "$fn" "$(sed -e 's/^....//' <<< "$fn")"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
for file in /path/to/MD18*.log; do
    name=$(echo "$file" | sed -E 's/.{4}(.*)/\1/')
    mv "$file" "$name"
done
```

This will remove the first 4 characters.

Comment: `${file#????}` would be more efficient and safer than piping the unquoted `$file` expansion through `sed`. Also, since you may not want to change every file's name jest because the start with `M`, you may want to remove the `MD18` prefix explicitly with `${file#MD18}`.  This is however already mentioned by Stéphane in their answer.